# Plantinga's logical argument for mind-body dualism

Tags: logic, philosophy

Some may feel this is not appropriate for the mathematics stack exchange, but it is a question in logic, and I feel it is entirely a good fit. The following argument has been put forth by the philosopher Alvin Plantinga in favor of mind-body dualism. I cannot see any logical error, but also have a hard time believing dualism has been demonstrated by a purely logical argument. If someone could please point out what is logically wrong with this, I would be appreciative.

The argument:

1. If A and B are identical then any statement of A is true of B and vice versa.
2. I can imagine existing without my body, for example in the body of a bird. I cannot imagine my body existing without my body.
3. By (2) we showed the existence of a statement that is true of (me) but not true of my (body).
4. By (1) my body and me are not identical.

End argument.

1. is true by definition. The first part of 2. is true by my experience -- I can imagine waking up in a bird's body, can you? The second part of 2. is true by my experience, and if I'm not mistaken it must be true of everybody's experience since one cannot imagine something logically invalid -- my body is my body by definition and cannot exist and not exist at the same time (P and $\not$ P cannot both be true). 3. and 4. are simply logical conclusions.

Has Plantinga rigorously proven an age old philosophical position defended by Descartes hundreds of years ago?

Update: Maybe this is better suited for the philosophy stack exchange? Could I please have it moved? Thank-you.

Comment: 2: When you imagine yourself existing "in the body of a bird", the bird's body is now yours. Because what does it mean to be inside the body of a bird, other than being the bird itself?

Comment: Then I could modify the argument above slightly: I can imagine existing without my body I have as I write this. ... My body as I write this and me are not identical. That's what Descartes wanted to show, e.g. that his physical body he was in was not the same as his mind.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mathematics. You don't need to "have it moved" to the philosophy stack exchange. Just go and ask the question there.

Comment: I think there is a question underlying this - "How can formal logic distinguish between 'mere' equality and 'essential' equality?" - which has a very satisfying *purely mathematical* answer (modal logic); I do agree this is borderline, but I think it should stay open.

Comment: @RobArthan The reason why I really wanted to post this question on this site is because the logic understanding of the participants on the math exchange is vastly superior than those on the philosophy exchange. For example, Schweber has a detailed explanation of the errors in Plantinga's argument, but Plantinga is considered one of the foremost philosophers in recent history, which may tell you something about the intellectual ability of philosophers.

Comment: I think we should avoid generating more heat than light, here . . .

Comment: There is a terrible equivocation going on here.  Sentence (2) can only be meaningful if "my mind" and "my body" refer to mental concepts which I have, so all this argument proves is that my mental concept of my body is not identical to my mental concept of my mind.

Comment: @EricWofsey, indeed.  This is also being argued under Noah's answer.

Comment: Alright, consider "It is possible that my mind is not my body" (true (arguably :P)) vs. "It is possibile that my mind is not my mind" (false). No thought here, just possibility (modality). We have $P(a, b)$ but not $P(a,a)$, so if (1) holds for a broad enough class of formulas - specifically, broad enough to include $P$ itself - then $a\not=b$. This brings the issue back to "when does (1) hold?", that is, "when does substitution work," which is what my answer is getting at below.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Well, I would say that if you accept "It is possible that my mind is not my body" and then conclude from this argument that "my mind" and "my body", referring to actual objective phenomena in the world, are not identical, then you are still equivocating.  If "my mind" and "my body" refer to objective phenomena, they either are identical or aren't.  Modality is only meaningful when talking about our mental concepts.  In other words, I would not say I'm disagreeing with your answer; I'm just saying the same thing in different words.

Comment: @EricWofsey I don't quite understand what you mean when you say, "Modality is only meaningful when talking about our mental concepts." One of the original uses of modality was to talk about possible actual objective futures. (And keep in mind I don't agree with Plantinga! I'm saying that if you grant a broad enough form of (1), which he seems to be, then his argument does work; but that that form of (1) is *so* broad as to be trivially false. The main reason I'm honing in on this particular aspect of the argument is that it is the one which seems to me to have the most *mathematical* content.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is barely relevant to this site, but ultimately that it is relevant, and the reason is that it is a good motivataion for **modal logic**.

Specifically, I would argue that **$(1)$ is not true**, at least the way that we might want it to be - for instance, "the eveningstar" and "the morningstar" are both Venus, but I can imagine that the eveningstar would not rise first in the morning, whereas I certainly can't imagine the morningstar not rising first in the morning (because that's how it's defined). Does this show that the eveningstar and the morningstar are different?

We model this sort of thing via *possible world semantics*, or *Kripke frames*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics. Briefly speaking, a Kripke frame (usually pictured as a directed graph) consists of a family of *worlds* (vertices) together with an "accessibility relation" (arrows). Each usual propositional sentence is true or false at each given world (worlds can disagree), but the Kripke frame structure lets us form *modal* statements as well, using "possible" and "necessary." Specifically, say that a world $w$ in a frame $K$ satisfies "it is necessary that $p$ holds" if, in every world accessible from $w$, $p$ is true. Similarly, "it is possible that $p$" is interpreted as "it is not necessary that $\neg p$."

For this example, the accessibility relation we're interested in is "$w'$ is an imaginable world, from the point of view of $w$." (It might be more natural to replace "world" by "state of affairs.")

In this context, (1) splits into two pieces:

- If $A=B$, then any purely *propositional* statement holds of $A$ iff it holds of $B$.
- If $A=B$, then any statement *at all* (including modalities) holds of $A$ iff it holds of $B$.

These two princples are very different, as the morningstar-eveningstar exapmle shows! We can have two formulas $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and worlds $w$ and $w'$, such that relative to $w$ $\alpha$ and $\beta$ define the same object, but relative to $w'$ they don't.

(NOTE: the question, "What graph properties should a Kripke frame satisfy in order to reflect such-and-such a logical situation?" is a great one, but not relevant to this question; for now, it's enough to realize that *there can be more than one world, at all.*)

---

So that said, I've actually skipped over a really important point!

I introduced worlds in Kripke frames as knowing about *propositional* statements. But we’re talking about *objects*, so we’re living in the world of *predicate logic*.

Specifically, we're trying to understand a statement of the form $(*)$ "The thing defined as '$A$' equals the thing defined as '$B$'." Intuitively, I want to say that there might be a world $w$ at which "$(*)$" is true but "necessarily $(*)$" is false. But this involves interpreting *names*, or *definitions*, across different worlds! How does that work?

It turns out this is a really huge deal - there’s lots of ways of potentially axiomatizing how Kripke frames “ought” to work in first-order logic, but there isn’t an obviously nicest one (see https://math.berkeley.edu/~buehler/First-Order%20Modal%20Logic.pdf, especially around 1.3). So the modal logic that’s being butchered (:P) by Plantinga’s argument is actually even more complicated than the run-of-the-mill propositional modal logic we know and love.

The mistake Plantinga’s making, though, does have a purely propositional analogue: it is not the case that “$p\iff q$” is the same as “It is necessary that $p\iff q$.” This is essentially the mistake being made: swapping identity for *necessary identity*.

Comment: He is looking for a property of A that does not hold of B.   It may not matter so much for that purpose what the nature of the language is in which the property is stated.  I think the key problem is rather (2); he is not describing an objective state of affairs about A and B unless the assertion is rephrased as "My mind, A, thinks that ...".  But this says nothing about what his body, B, might think.  It could have the identical thoughts as mind A (and that is precisely what we would expect if there is no difference between A and B).

Comment: My point is that (1) isn't true of properties involving modalities (like "it is imaginable that. . ."), so the rest of his argument breaks. By the way, I think your objection to (2) is weak. (1) can be strengthened to "if A=B, then, if we take a true statement, and substitute some occurences of A for B, then we get a true statement," which is no less plausible than (1) itself; and then "I can imagine I am not my body" and "I can imagine I am not me" provides a counterexample to the strengthened version of (1). So the problem really has to lie in the conflation of kinds of equality.

Comment: I agree that the substitution principle in (1) is questionable but it's not so clear that the modal analysis is the way to criticize it.   If there is a sufficiently definite, clear, objective, computable (etc) property of A that fails for B, the argument works.  The problem as I see is that that (2) is *not saying anything at all* unless it is made precise in a way where it clearly could hold for both A and B.

Comment: Another way to say it (or a related "it") is that if you run through his argument, making at all times the assumption that A and B are identical, but recognizing that A (his mind) can perfectly well hold unfounded beliefs that it is the "A" and not the body "B", nothing contradicts the running assumption A=B.  The body, which is secretly also the mind, would hold the same beliefs, and the only distinctions are external ones in our description of this scenario in terms of distinct labels A and B.  Imagining things doesn't make them so.

Comment: I disagree - (2) is saying something. To make it clearer, consider the ternary predicate "Im(a, b, c)=a can imagine that b is not c." Then (2) is the assertion, "'Im(me, me, body)' is true but 'Im(me, me, me)' is false," which is a clear contradiction with the strengthened form of (1) (by substituting "me" for "body"). When you say "imagining things doesn't make them so," you're missing the point of Plantinga's argument - being able to imagine $A\not=B$, but not being able to imagine $A\not=A$, is interpreted via (1) as a proof that $A\not=B$.

Comment: By the way, on the relevance of modal logic to Plantinga: note that this is the language he has used to formalize his own arguments (see e.g. http://www.jstor.org/stable/2184280?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: No, the correct formalization of (2) is the obviously much weaker Im(A, A's imagination of "me", A's imagination of "my body").  Distilled to its essentials, this property that purportedly distinguishes A and B is P(X)= "X's understanding of '*me*' differs from X's understanding of '*my body*' ".   This property depends only on X and it can equally be true of A and B.  The only way for the argument to do the work it is supposed to do is if there is a conflation of  X's self (resp., body) and X's imagination of those.   That is, "imagining things makes them so" is the crux of the argument.

Answer (score 10):

1. If A and B are identical then any statement of A is true of B and vice versa.
2. I think the unidentified serial killer is a horrible person. I do not think my son is a horrible person.
3. Therefore, my son is innocent.

Further reading: [masked man fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masked_man_fallacy).

---

Also, even if one accepts the argument as stated, the kind of mind-body dualism it supports is in any case an extremely mild one, of the same sort as the President/Obama dualism. (Replacing "me" and "my body" with "the President" and "Obama" in the posted argument is a fun exercise.) That doesn't mean that Obama is not the President, nor does it confer upon the office of the President some mysterious metaphysical status.

Are you sure what you've written is exactly Plantinga's argument? Perhaps there is some subtlety lost in your paraphrasing?

Answer (score -1):

He is proving the wrong proposition for his purposes.  What he should establish is:

> my (body) cannot imagine existing without its body, for example, in the body of a bird.

If his (body) *can* imagine that, then we have not found something to differentiate his mind and his body.

Comment: The comment under Noah Schweber's answer further explicates this point.